# htaccess query string rewrite in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have an issue with the rewriting of the query string.

The URL I have is the following:

localhost/www/whours.com/index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth

and I would like to translate it in:

localhost/www/whours.com/login_controller/noAuth

In my htaccess, currently, there is the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^comp=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  www/whours.com/%1?
```

and in the index.php:

```
// Getting the absolute root path
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

include_once("App/Core/Config/config.php");
include_once(CORE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Include/autoloader.php");

//echo ('location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?comp=login_controller/noAuth");
if (!isset($_GET['comp']))
{
    header('location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?comp=login_controller/noAuth");
}
$app = new Application();
$app->run();
```

When I am contacting the URL in localhost it seems the htaccess is not applied and the result is page Error 404 with the following URL: localhost/www/whours.com/index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth

Could you please give me a suggestion or an help to find where is placed the issue?

Many thanks in advance.
Simone

Answer (score 0):

If you want `http://www.example.com/www/whours.com/login_controller/noAuth` rewritten into `http://www.example.com/www/whours.com/index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth`, you must have it the other way round

```
RewriteRule ^www/whours.com/(.+)$ /www/whours.com/index.php?comp=$1 [L]
```

---

Although this looks like `www/whours.com` might be the document root of your web page. In this case the URL would be rather `http://www.example.com/login_controller/noAuth` and the rule must look like

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?comp=$1 [L]
```

---

To rewrite `http://localhost/www/whours.com/` or `http://www.whours.com` to `/index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth` replace your rule with

```
RewriteRule ^www/whours.com/?$ /index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth [L]
```

on localhost. This assumes, that .../www/whours.com is your document root, i.e. you have `DocumentRoot /path/to/www/whours.com` somewhere in your Apache configuration files.

On your production server (www.whours.com), use

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Olaf. www/whours.com currently is my document root effectively because in production it will become www.whours.com. I would like to obtain that what I'm passing in the php instruction 'header' (localhost/www/whours.com/index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth) will be translated in the URL (so seen by the users and the crawlers) localhost/www/whours.com/login_controller/noAuth - not the contrary where the query string is visible. Do you have any suggestion? How can I modify the htaccess?

Comment: You want the user enter `http://localhost/www/whours.com/login_controller/noAuth` into the browser?

Comment: No, I expect the user enter into the browser: localhost/www/whours.com/ (in dev) and www.whours.com (in production). The redirect to index.php is done automatically by the webserver. Is for what I am expecting which I made the redirection in php to the URL with query string in order to be change by the htaccess

Comment: I would expect, also, that internally php is still seeing the query string (comp=login_controller/noAuth) in order to be parsed by the router through the $_GET['comp']. Please ask me if you need more details and thanks so much

Comment: So the user enters `http://localhost/www/whours.com/` or `http://www.whours.com` and the server rewrites to `.../index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth`?

Comment: Not exactly: the user enters localhost/www/whours.com/ or www.whours.com and the server should rewrite to /index.php/login_controller/noAuth . At the same time, internally, the server shoud see the path like /index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth in order to be parsed with the $_GET

Comment: This means you have already some rule, which translates from `/index.php/login_controller/noAuth` to `/index.php?comp=login_controller/noAuth`?

Comment: In my htaccess I have the following: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^comp=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  www/whours.com/%1?
 
The only RewriteRule is this shown in the htaccess